# Model in backbone client is not destroyed until i refresh the page and delete him again

Tags: javascript, web-services, rest, backbone.js

I built a backbone REST client with the list of the contacts. The list is populated with the data from the server. Every list item is a separate model with a delete button, which invokes this function:

```
deleteContact: function(){
this.model.destroy();
this.remove();
}
```

My problem is: when i click the delete button, the model dissapears from the page, but no DELETE request is send to the server. So when i refresh the page, this model is still there. But after i refresh it, the delete buttons now works properly, but only to the models it got from the server (all models I created prior to the refreshing). If I add any new model, i have to manually refresh the page every time to make the delete buttons work on them. (The POST request are send every time right.

Where might be the problem: in the ItemView, in the ItemListView, or maybe somewhere else?

Comment: If your model doesn't have an `id` attribute, the `DELETE` request will not be sent to the server. When you add the new model, are you returning an `id` from the server?

Comment: That's is probably the cause, but when i add new model, this is how my server responds: `{"entry": {"Name": "-", "PhoneNb": "-", "Surname": "-", "id": 5}}` where dashes are the inputs from the user, and the id is generated by server.

Comment: why don't use see this.model.get('id') in your deleteContact before this.model.destroy()?

Comment: `this.model.get('id')` returns no value, because the id of my object is not defined. The `id` exists only on the server, so i would have to somehow retrieve it from it.